# sql query analyzer xml resultset truncated

Tags: sql-server

I store some xml data in a table.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, value) (1, '<xml>...</xml>')

SELECT value FROM table
```

but when I do a select query from query analyzer the 'value' field is showing truncated xml.

How can I see the full xml?

Comment: What is the type of the field? Can you show the SQL for the table definition?

Comment: Query Analyser or Management Studio? Are you still using 2000 client tools?

Comment: Results to text, results to grid? Make sure to use grid. Is value an XML column? If not, try CONVERT(XML, value) then the output should appear clickable.

Comment: It's a nvarchar(max) field. And I'm using Sql Server 2008 R2 Management Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the options for query results.

Comment: I did change it. Tools -> Options -> Query Results -> Results to Text -> Maximum number of characters displayed in each column is set to 8192

Comment: It only shows 255 characters. I did a SELECT LEN(value) FROM table.

Comment: Are you saying LEN(value) returns 255?

Comment: Sorry my bad. I had a storedprocedure to insert the value, the parameter was varchar(255) instead of nvarchar(max). The whole time it was the bug in sp and not the query analyzer. Everything works perfect.